# Why can't I push a new view controller onto the current view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am using the following code and getting the following errors:

[image: Showing code used and errors with code]

EDIT: See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k713X.png) if you cannot read the image above!

The "ChangePasscode" is currently declared as a class and is a view controller with .h and .m files along with a .nib file.

Why are these issues happening, what can I do to fix them?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds just like ['Receiver type “CCParticleBatchNode” for class message is a forward declaration'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7965929/590956) which got asked yesterday.  There are some pretty good answers for this, but you might want to follow that Q.

Comment: not really relavant... Answers here are much better / more useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to say that you've not imported `ChangePasscode.h` in your current file.

**Update:** In response to comment thread below, you'll need to actually create a nav structure if you want to push view controllers. The preferred way in iOS 5 is as follows:

```
// AppDelegate.h
// …Other existing code
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navController;
@end

// AppDelegate.m
@synthesize navController;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  self.window.rootViewController = navController;
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: correct! But... I get this error when compiling: http://f.cl.ly/items/0x2t1A2c12383d2M130h/2ndXCodeIssue.tiff

Comment: Try a Clean (Product > Clean). You can also clean the build folder by holding down the Option key when you click the Clean menu choice.

Comment: it works now, because I changed "#import "ChangePasscode.m"" to "#import "ChangePasscode.h"" - although when the action to push the new view controller is called, nothing happens? The code is exactly the same. Nothing in the NSLog either :(

Comment: There's not much to go on…assuming you actually have a navigation controller system implemented, try an `NSLog` to see if `cpscreen` is nil or not. Also, which `NSLog` are you referring to?

Comment: Is there anything else I can push the new view controller from other than "navigationController"? I tried "window" but it didn't work because I am not working in an App Delegate...

Comment: No, you'd only push view controllers to a nav controller. How did you set up your nav controller structure—did you start out with a Navigation template, create a Navigation Controller structure in Interface Builder or alloc/init a `UINavigationController`, set its `rootViewController` property and then add it as a subview? If you have not done any of that, then you haven't created an actual nav controller to push to. `NSLog` both `self.navigationController` and `cpscreen` and see what you get.

Comment: I started out with a simple view project with one view - would this change anything? How can I create a navigation controller if I don't have one? Although in my AppDelegate.m file, there are quite a few mentions of "ViewController"

Comment: Yes, the Single View project has no support for navigation. See my updated answer with code to create a nav controller stack first. Then you can push view controllers and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't like the "initWithRootViewController:viewController" bit, because it still says that it is undeclared. My viewController is actually part of my AppDelegate.h file - although I have imported that at the top :S

Comment: Right I now have it working after declaring the viewController line. But when I press the button, it opens a new window but it is blank - it does not show my other xib file (called "ChangePasscode.xib") - what can I do to show this?

Comment: If you've made the correct connections to File's Owner in `ChangePasscode.xib`, just use the standard `init` rather than `initWithNibName:bundle:`

Comment: But there is no "initWithNibName:bundle:" to replace?

Comment: Yes there is, I'm looking at it in your screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

change `[NSBundle mainBundle]` to nil
make sure you have import ChangePasscode.h on top of the M file

Comment: Fixed that error because I hadn't used the "#import" code. However, I now get this error when compiling: http://f.cl.ly/items/0x2t1A2c12383d2M130h/2ndXCodeIssue.tiff

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking this is a classic case of circular references. Maybe the two classes reference each other? Because of this forward declaration you might get all kinds of warnings when trying to reference the class name or properties of the class that has the forward declaration.

Where all have you included `ChangePasscode`. Also use `#import` rather than `#include`.

**UPDATE**: To solve your `ld: duplicate symbol...` error

It seems that you are compiling the same class `ChangePasscode` two times in different places of your code. This may happen in the following cases.

1. You have put the same class implementation into two different files
2. You actually have just one implementation of this class, however you are also linking in your project a framework or library containing a class whose name is exactly the same of yours.
3. You could also get this error if you mistakenly let XCode's auto-complete for #import statements specify the '.m" file for the 'duplicate' class instead of the '.h'.

Try finding in the whole project your class and make sure only one copy is available within your project.

Comment: Fixed that error because I hadn't used the "#import" code. However, I now get this error when compiling: http://f.cl.ly/items/0x2t1A2c12383d2M130h/2ndXCodeIssue.tiff

Comment: Clearly you have redefined some class variables across .m files. correct that by renaming the conflicting names & you are good to go.

Comment: I've checked and there are absolutely no class references at all :/

Comment: there has to be your error states the there was a duplicate symbol in your `ChangePasscode`. So please look again.

Comment: when it says "duplicate symbol" what exactly does that mean? What else am I supposed to be looking for? I have searched all over several times and there are absolutely no class references! :(

Comment: it works now, because I changed "#import "ChangePasscode.m"" to "#import "ChangePasscode.h"" - although when the action to push the new view controller is called, nothing happens? The code is exactly the same. Nothing in the NSLog either :(

Comment: oH!!! you dont import `.m` You always import `.h` files. Then your duplicate symbol problem is solved. Now move on to see why your viewcontroller is not showing anything.

Comment: you have solved it. You are able to push a view controller. If your view controller is not working please open another question with details. Am considering this question answered...

Answer (score 0):

use

```
@class ChangePasscode;
```

rather than using

```
#import ChangePasscode.h
```

Comment: That's what I was doing but had the errors explained in the question so I changed to #import and my new error is: http://f.cl.ly/items/0x2t1A2c12383d2M130h/2ndXCodeIssue.tiff

Comment: It seems that you are compiling the same ChangePasscode class two times in different places of your code. This may happen in the following cases.

You have put the same class implementation into two different files;

You actually have just one implementation of this class, however you are also linking in your project a framework or library containing a class whose name is exactly the same of yours.

Try finding in the whole project your class and make sure only one copy is available within your project.

Comment: how can I do this? What do you mean? :S

Comment: check your project directory for ChangePasscode class and make sure that there is SINGLE ChangePasscode.h and ChangePasscode.m file.
There may be possibility that you have added same named class reference to your project from some other location.

Comment: there aren't any class references in the whole project at all and I have done as you have said but the issue still remains :(

Comment: it works now, because I changed "#import "ChangePasscode.m"" to "#import "ChangePasscode.h"" - although when the action to push the new view controller is called, nothing happens? The code is exactly the same. Nothing in the NSLog either :(